# Numbers under a note

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

I have recently got a new piece of sheet music for the piano. I play the clarinet in band so I have never really had to learn bass clef. I thought I would surprise my boyfriend by playing our song for him. The only downside to this plan is I cant really understand the music. I came across a Half note with a five beneath it. Would someone please tell me what it means? The song is in the key of F major.

Comment: It is likely a [fingering number](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/23561/numbers-above-notes-in-piano-sheet-music).

Answer (score 0):

The 5 is for [fingering on the piano](http://www.pianoscales.org/fingerings.html). It's telling the player to use their pinky on the note. You can disregard it if you are not playing piano.